# How to set dynamically the maxSize of a TextField according to its width?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textfield, lwuit-container

There is a `TextField` inside a `Container` and other `components` in the `Form`. According to the available space for the `Container` the `TextField` has a preferred `width`. How can I set programmatically a `maxSize` , that is the maximum number of `characters` that can be entered , to the `TextField` ?

Answer (score 2):

For set a maximum number of characters to a `TextField` you should use `setDefaultMaxSize(int value)`. So, you must catch the width of the `Container` and set this maxSize according to this size.

Comment: But there is the problem of the font size ! And every letters have not the same size ! So how to know how many caracters should be set ?

Comment: I use to do it by hand. Catch the fontSize too and modify the setDefaultMaxSize. Did you try with setGrowByContent?

Comment: maxSize and width of container are not the same ; the former is the nb of chars and the last is mesurement in pixel !